# MySQL query with increment based on already existing values and only in rows with column "Confirmed" not zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is manually edited from a webstore. I would like to do this faster with a query.

```
Table: OC_Orders
```

I would like to auto increment column `'Invoice number'` in all rows if column `'status id'` (is not zero / 1-5). And I would like to start from a certain row (the next row after last manual input).

Auto increment column `'invoice number'` if column `'status_id'` is >1 in table `OC_Orders`.

Start on "oldest" row with `'invoice number' = NULL` and increment from "newest" row with `'invoice number' > NULL`.

Comment: Your requirements need a little clarification.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, if you want to do this with a query, the php tag is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Your requirements need a little clarification. Do you want status_id to not be 0-5; or not be 0, with the other values it could be being 1-5? Is there anything that designates a manual row from a non-manual row? Do you want to reset the starting value of the auto increment to be the next valid value after the latest manual entry? By all rows, do you mean all rows or all rows after the last manual entry that don't have a 0 status_id?

Comment: I have updated the question, maybe its better now. Thanks

Comment: You contradict yourself a little. Do you want status id from 1 - 5 or status id > 1 (this would be limited to 2 -5)? For invoice numbers that aren't null, the comparison you're looking for is `IS NOT NULL`, not `> NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
select @rn := max(invoicenumber)
from orders;

update orders o
    set invoicenumber = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where status <> 0 and id > $id
    order by invoicenumber;
```

That is, you can use variables in `update` statements to set values in this way.